# sort x axis in melted frame R

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

I have a data frame and I am binding the rowids to the frame.
When I try to plot the graph with rowIds on X axis, I see the values sorted alphabetically. How to plot the graph with Ids sorted numerically and display on X axis

```
rates<-data.frame(rates)
id <- rownames(rates)
rates <- cbind(id=id, rates)
meltedData2 <- melt(rates,id.vars="id", na.rm = TRUE)
cdf <- ggplot(meltedData2, aes(x=id,group=1))+geom_line(aes(y=value,colour=variable),stat="identity")
```

Comment: Try `seq_along()` perhaps?

Comment: Can you add some simple data to make a reproducible example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: Just adding an example plot would help.